# How can I limit access to a page and/or video for a set amount of time and then never again by IP?

Tags: javascript, time

I am trying to make a classroom style video that will play only once per viewer. I don't mind if they refresh, but the page will only be accessible to them for a limited time. I found some code that would be relevant, but it uses a cookie.

```
<script language="Javascript">
function played(){
var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
var c = ca[i];
while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
if (c.indexOf("played=") == 0) return 1;
}
var date = new Date();
var days = 7;
date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
document.cookie = "played=1"+"; expires="+date.toGMTString()+"; path=/";
return 0;
}
if(played()==0){
document.write("<embed src=\"http://www.youtube.com/v/xxxxxxxxW&autoplay=1\"                             
type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" wmode=\"transparent\" width=\"740\"         
height=\"400\"></embed>");
}
 else{
document.write("<embed src=\"http://www.youtube.com/v/xxxxxxxx\"     
type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" wmode=\"transparent\"width=\"740\"height=\"400\"></embed>");
}
</script>
```

Any idea how to do this per IP, or maybe even device and allow the time limit instead of page view/cookie? Please help me understand how to approach this.

Comment: If it's once per user, and in a classroom setting, does that mean they'll all be on a local network? If so, the public IP is almost guaranteed to be the same for every user.

Comment: apart from this dont use `document.write`. this will cause many security issues

Comment: @fubar I agree if it's a lan setting, unless the domain is pointed to a internal ip this will crash and burn miserably.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of operations are best done on the server side. As any client side code can be bypassed by simple code editing, userscript, or browser extension. Especially if what you really need is the MAC (physical address) or internal IP address.
If you don't have access to the server your options are limited but there is still hope. Depending on the browser (and if they have java/flash/silverlight) used by client there are ways to write a persistent cookies take a look at [evercookie](https://github.com/samyk/evercookie).
 **Please make sure to read the *caveats* and make sure you understand the implications!**